# Random color between two selected rgb-colors (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, random, colors, rgb

With the following js-snippet...

```
rgb(' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 128).toString(10) + ','
      + Math.floor(Math.random() * 128).toString(10) + ','
      + Math.floor(Math.random() * 128).toString(10) + ')
```

...it's possible to random "dark" colors.

Is there a way to randomize between to colors? One in black and the other in blue - and the random color "between" them? Tricky or easy?

Comment: RGB essentially represents a 3-dimensional 'space'. Please clarify what exactly you mean by 'between' two colors. Do you mean 'any color where the R, G, and B components are between the R, G, and B components of these colors' or something else?

Comment: If by between colours, you mean what I think you mean, you would be better off working in HSL. It would be quite trivial in that and converting from and back to RGB is trivial as well.

Comment: Thx for reply! I mean a random color between #000000 or rgb(0,0,0) and #00CFEF or rgb(0,207,239)

Answer (score 2):

RGB is black at 0 0 0, and continiues to brighten up to white at 255 255 255.

If you just want a couple of tints, try this website: http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.htm
Mouseover the pallet and look below how the R/G/B number changes.

After that, its only the matter of writing an algorithm to get shades of any particular color.(use math.random in a range of your choosing)

`Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 50` gives a random number between 10 and 50.

Here's how you get (roughly) all the tints:

```
R+(X * (255-R))  
G+(X * (255-G))  
B+(X * (255-B))
```

**R**,**G** and **B** in your case will be `0`,`207` and `239` respectively.
**X** is the factor of tinting(use `0.25`, `0.5` or `0.75` to get round numbers). The bigger the factor, the more it will brighten.

For example:

```
0+(0.25 * (255-0))  
207+(0.25 * (255-207))  
239+(0.25 * (255-239))
```

Will give you `0,219,243`, one tint brighter than `0,207,239`. Rinse and repeat!



**Edit2:** If you just want shades between `0,207,239` and black, there's a simpler way of achieving it.

Keep subtracting an X(again, a modifier, the bigger it is, the more it will darken with each pass) from all three values.
For an X=20:

`0,207,239` > `0,187,219` Will be a darker shade of blue, and once you reach 0,0,0 you'll be at black.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thx for your reply, actually I don't understand the algorithm you mentioned :-) But these would be the two rgb-colors: rgb(0,0,0) and rgb(0,207,239)

Comment: @Sebastian Edited. I'll leave the coding to actually get a random tint to you :)

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm glad you could help. Now I get it. But there is a tiny but, because it should be a random generated color ("around" this blue in direction to black). These sample colors show only the "one" color, I've chosen.

Comment: @Sebastian Refer to Edit 2, hopefully i got it right this time!

Answer (score 0):

To create a random number between two colors, the technique should be creating a random number between `0` and `1` and use it to get the same color percent  in each channel, for example, the next code tries to get a random color between `rgb(0, 0, 0)` and `rgb(0, 207, 239)`:

```
var random = Math.random();
var red = 0 + Math.floor((0 - 0) * random);
var green = 0 + Math.floor((207 - 0) * random);
var blue = 0 + Math.floor((239 - 0) * random);
```

I've used some part of a `JavaScript` utility that I created some time ago to create the next example, you can generate with it random colors between two colors (you can use strings as these: `#FFF`, `#FFFFFF` or `rgb(255, 255, 255)`)

```js
function RandomColor (color1, color2) {

    var _regs = {
        "hex3"  : /^#([a-f\d])([a-f\d])([a-f\d])$/i,
        "hex6"  : /^#([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i,
        "rgb"   : /^rgb\s*\(\s*([\d\.]+%?)\s*\,\s*([\d\.]+%?)\s*\,\s*([\d\.]+%?)\s*\)$/
    };

    var _obj1 = getValues(color1);
    var _obj2 = getValues(color2);

    //---Get the colors
    function getValues (color) {

        var values = false;

        for (var prop in _regs) {

            if (_regs[prop].test(color)) {

                values = {};

                values.r = color.replace(_regs[prop], "$1");
                values.g = color.replace(_regs[prop], "$2");
                values.b = color.replace(_regs[prop], "$3");

                if (prop === "rgb") {
 
                    values.r = Number(values.r);
                    values.g = Number(values.g);
                    values.b = Number(values.b);

                } else {

                    values.r = parseInt(values.r, 16);
                    values.g = parseInt(values.g, 16);
                    values.b = parseInt(values.b, 16);

                }

                break;

            }

        }

        return values;

    }

    //---str_pad
    function str_pad (str, pad_length, pad_string, pad_type) {

        var len = pad_length - str.length;
        if (len < 0) { return str };
        var pad = new Array(len + 1).join(pad_string);
        if (pad_type === "STR_PAD_LEFT") { return pad + str };
        return str + pad;

    }

    //---Get a value
    function getRandom (c1, c2, pcent) {

        var color = c1 + Math.floor((c2 - c1) * pcent);

        if (color < 0) color = 0;

     return str_pad(color.toString(16), 2, "0", "STR_PAD_LEFT");

    }

    //---Get a random color
    this.getColor = function () {

        if (_obj1 && _obj2) {

            var random = Math.random();

            var r = getRandom(_obj1.r, _obj2.r, random);
            var g = getRandom(_obj1.g, _obj2.g, random);
            var b = getRandom(_obj1.b, _obj2.b, random);

            return "#" + r + g + b;

        }

        return false;

    };

}

var doc = document;
var link = doc.querySelector("#link");
var thumb = doc.querySelector(".thumb");
var generator = new RandomColor("#000", "rgb(0, 207, 239)");

link.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {

    evt.preventDefault();

    var color = generator.getColor();

    if (color) {
        thumb.style.background = color;
        thumb.innerHTML = color;
    }
});
```

```css
#link {
    display: block;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-align: center;
}

.thumb {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    color: white;
    font-family: Arial;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -moz-transition: background .25s ease;
    -webkit-transition: background .25s ease;
    transition: background .25s ease;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<a id="link" href="#">Generate a random color between #000000 and #00CFEF</a>
<br>
<div class="thumb"></div>
```